# Erro tentando definir ou ler o valor de variáveis já definidas - System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, exceção, windows-phone, variáveis, windows-phone-8-1

estou tendo problemas com este código.
Sempre que ele roda, causa uma exceção do tipo `System.NullReferenceException`.

```
// Clear out the Array of code words
        wordBuffer = null;
        Int32 syntaxCount = 0;
        // Create the regular expression object to match against the string
        Regex defaultRegex = new Regex(@"\w+|[^A-Za-z0-9_ \f\t\v]",
        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
        Match wordMatch;
        // Loop through the string and continue to record
        // words and symbols and their corresponding positions and lengths
        for (wordMatch = defaultRegex.Match(s); wordMatch.Success; wordMatch = wordMatch.NextMatch())
        {
            var word = new Object[3] { wordMatch.Value, wordMatch.Index, wordMatch.Length };
            wordBuffer[syntaxCount] = word;
            Debug.WriteLine("Found = " + word[0]);
            syntaxCount++;
        }
        // return the number of symbols and words
        return syntaxCount;
```

A exceção ocorre nessas duas linhas(se eu removo a primeira, a exceção ocorre na segunda):

```
Debug.WriteLine("Found = " + word[0]);
                syntaxCount++;
```

Especificamente quando tento pegar o valor de `word[0]`, E na segunda linha com a variável `syntaxCount`, mas nenhuma delas está com o valor nulo, como vocês podem ver na imagem abaixo:

[image]
A variável "s" é apenas uma linha de uma RichEditBox, `word[0]` tem um valor, então porque está causando a exceção `NullReferenceException`? `syntaxCount` tem um valor também :/

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você define a variável `wordBuffer` como nula.

> wordBuffer = null;

e depois tenta usá-la para armazenar uma palavra.

> wordBuffer[syntaxCount] = word;

Você deve substituir a linha `wordBuffer = null;` por algo assim: `wordBuffer = new string[{tamanho do vetor}]`, substituindo `{tamanho do vetor}` pelo tamanho desejado para o vetor.

Comment: Como comentei na resposta acima, eu não tinha conhecimento da quantidade total de itens que seriam adicionados a array, então não seria possível definir um tamanho para ela. O que me atendeu melhor foi uma `List<>`. A sua explicação sobre o que ocorreu foi mais completa, obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Reproduzi o código aqui e percebi o seguinte:

> wordBuffer = null; //é um array, altere pelo código abaixo ou na forma que achar melhor

```
var wordBuffer = new Array[20];
```

> Match(s) //(s) não vi a declaração talvez esteja mais acima do código, de qualquer forma
>   veja o exemplo abaixo

```
string s = "ab!@#$#@!";
```

Boa sorte. @marlon-santos

Comment: Obrigado, mas percebi que estava fazendo errado desde o começo. Além desse erro óbvio, eu não tinha conhecimento do total de `strings` que seriam adicionas à array, no entanto a aproximação correta seria uma `List<>`. Assim ficaria até mais fácil de manusear e com o código mais limpo.